# C Programming about choosing my version of a function

Tags: c

In function main() {...}

1) #include header file string.h

2) I prototype my own file, call it strcpy:

```
**char *strcpy(char *strSource , const char *dest);**
```

3) I also wish to use the "real" *strlen* function in string.h in main().

4) In another compilation file I have my version of strcpy.

Question:  How can I get the linker to choose my version of strcpy instead of the prototype in string.h?

```
enter code here
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
char *strcpy(char *source , const char *dest); 
void main()
{
char *s, *d;
strcpy(s,d);
getch();
}

#include <stdio.h>
char *strcpy(char *strDestination, const char *strSource)
{
char *ptr;
printf("made it!");
return ptr;
}
```

Comment: The title and tag don't suggest the same language. Please change it.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this? Seems a little nefarious. :P I mean why not just name your strcpy something different, i.e. `myStrcpy();`

Comment: Namespace issues aside... `const char *` means a pointer to chars that you cannot change.  Why would your `dest` be a `const char*`??

Comment: The linker cares nothing about the declaration!  Headers are not libraries.  Libraries are not headers.

Comment: @HostileFork: He used the [wrong order](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/) of arguments, should be `char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source );`.

Comment: @gbtimmon - Wonderful suggestion.  However, I am trying to understand the way C works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that in C. That's one of the reasons why C++ introduces *namespaces*.

The only thing you can do is use a non-conflicting name for your own functions.

Comment: Thanks. Using non-conflicting names is obvious, but are you sure "you can't do that in C"?  My question is not whether it is standard, the question is: can it be done.

Comment: [You can abuse the preprocessor to use namespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389827/namespaces-in-c), but it's ugly.

Comment: rather not use namespaces because it's not pure C.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a standard thing to do, and I'm pretty sure that if you can do it at all, you will have to read the manual for your linker.  And if you try to port this, you will need to read the manual for each linker for each platform to which you try to port this.

The more usual way to do things is to write your own functions with your own names.  If you need to hook functionality in a standard library, you would get the source for that library and build your own version.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and suggestion.  No, I don't want to get into that much work!