# How do you prevent names from colliding in C

Tags: c, namespaces, collision

Let's say I have a two files : stack.h and queue.h. Both want to implement the function add(). If I include stack.h and queue.h in the same main.c for example, there will be a collision.

What is the recommended way to implement the add() function in both files?

Comment: As the other answers said, and as in any programming language, all libraries you include must have a sane design with dedicated names which you accept. Otherwise, you will always have collisions in any programming language. Eg, if you include a header "terribad.h" which happens to reserve all variables on the planet, you might want to reconsider having "terribad.h" inside your project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you already have a queue and a stack implementation tested, and referred to elsewhere.. you can do some preprocessor tricks like this:

```
#define _STACK
#define _QUEUE

#ifdef _QUEUE
#define add queue_add
  #include "queue.h"
#undef add
#endif

#ifdef _STACK
#define add stack_add
  #include "stack.h"
#undef add
#endif

int main()
{
   stack_add();
   queue_add();
}
```

My advice is - refactor the code base to use non-clashing naming convention instead of generic function names like `add` and `subtract` and the rest.

If you are a fan of object oriented programming style and like the whole "add", "modify" concept then use function pointers inside the queue and stack structure.

```
#define TYPE int

typedef struct tagStruct{
   TYPE *dataBuffer;
   void (*add)(TYPE data);
   void (*modify)(TYPE data, int index);
   void (*deleteEverything)()
}stack;
```

and in the `init(stack)` method, assign `add()`, `modify()` and `deleteEverything()` to different functions that have no name-collision(likewise for queue)

Then you begin to see `stack` and `queue` as ENTITIES rather than bunch-of-functions.

You can then do this:

```
stack stc;
init(stc); /*sets up the function pointers*/
stc.add(10);
stc.modify(30,0);
stc.deleteEverything();
```

Comment: @KeithNicholas yeah - but if he already has stack and queue defined, he will have to do something ugly. Just so he does not break other parts of the code that either use `stack.h` or `queue.h`

Answer (score 7):

If this is pure C, the simplest common solution is to use do-it-yourself namespacing on the functions relative to the name of the module or data structure that they apply to. e.g.

```
stack_add(...)
queue_add(...)
```

You will find examples of this in pretty much all large pure-C projects:

```
pthread_mutex_lock() // POSIX/UNIX, used for locking a mutex
CGRectMake()         // iOS, used to fill in a CGRect structure
RtlZeroMemory()      // WinNT, "Rtl" indicates the module it belongs to
```

Your question was about "exported" (public) function names, but note too that when your .c files have private helper functions, you can mark them `static` which tells the compiler that they are used only from within that file, so your naming can be a little looser for them knowing they won't collide elsewhere.

Comment: See this question for ideas on C namespaces, although IMHO it's a bit overkill: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389827/namespaces-in-c