# c\c++ - Functions with unions as arguments to meet specific requirements

Tags: c++, c, arguments, compatibility, unions

I'm engineering library to provide functionality for one device. This device has some common operations but different algorithms to accomplish these operations. I want one function prototype for one particular operation, not a bunch of them, say instead of:

```
Alg1_Foo();
Alg2_Foo();
...
```

I want this:

```
Foo(alg);
```

But I don't want to pass alg as separate argument, because functions will have a lot of arguments even without it, they will have arguments for identification and/or authorization of the device, in argument, out argument (at least one of them), so I think it will be annoying to add alg as a separate argument.

So my idea is to provide solution like this one:

```
Foo(const SomeUnion& some_union);
```

Where:

```
union SomeUnion {
  AlgId alg_id;
  alg1::SomeStruct alg1_some_struct;
  alg2::SomeStruct alg2_some_struct;

  SomeUnion(alg1::SomeStruct some_struct) { alg1_some_struct = some_struct; };
  SomeUnion(alg2::SomeStruct some_struct) { alg2_some_struct = some_struct; };
};
```

And the structures of particular algorithms will be like this:

```
namespace alg1 {
  struct SomeStruct {
    static const AlgId alg_id = ALG1;
    . . .
  };
}
```

So if want to perform say alg1, we pass appropriate structure to Foo and it works in C++, say

```
alg1::SomeStruct a;
Foo(a);
```

But I want my library to maintain possibilities of pure C. Of course I need to:

1. remove references and replace them with pointers;
2. remove namespaces (we can still emulate them with the help of structures (this thread may be helpful for those interested: [Namespaces in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389827/namespaces-in-c));
3. replace C++-style of defining structs to that from C and define also name in tag namespace (typedef struct tagStruct {...} Struct;);
4. remove functions from inside structures and unions.

But though I can't understand if it's possible to accomplish what I want to do with maintenance of C... Do you see the way? Or is it just simplier to pass alg_id as a separate argument not to bother with unions and structures (but I want to avoid it if possible)?

Comment: So why don't you want separate functions for each algorithm?

Comment: What is the question? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: overengineered comes to mind.

Comment: Mayhap it's overengineered but we have the library which was engineered by the person who worked in the company before me and we have a lot of prototypes for each separate algorithm. I won't say it's easy to maintain them, say, if logic of particular operation changes, and we need to change all the prototypes connected with it. It's just a proposal what was written above, if it's impossible to accomplish in C I will accept it and leave separate functions or add alg_id as argument. But if you have some clues they will be appreciated.

Comment: With C++ you can overload `Foo` to take a different struct for each algorithm.  So you're really defining a bunch of functions (which you say you don't want to do, but don't given any reason why), they just all have the same name.

Comment: See my comment to the answer of Mats Petersson, I give my motivation there. Overloading of functions won't do because though I use C++ I want this library to work with C applications also.

Answer (score 3):

To me, this seems like a typical case where someone is trying to solve a problem "the wrong way".

If you have "lots of arguments" to a function, then using a `struct` is fine. But hiding "which function you are actually calling" inside such a `struct`, and then having several variants of`struct` inside a `union`, now we're trying to stuff too much into one function. Start to split the function so that it only takes one `struct` - remove your `union` as an argument - that's just wrong. [I have worked with code that does similar things to this - the chances of sneaking in some code that does the wrong thing and causes some hard to find error because you passed the wrong type of `union` arguments into the function makes this really a poor solution]. If you pass the wrong type of structure to a plain functions then the compiler tells you. If you fill in the wrong part of a union, the code using the "right" part of the structure will get "weird" data [quite possibly undefined behaviour] - this type of bug can be darn difficult to find.

So yes, split your functions, remove the union!

**Edit:** 
One suggestion that comes to mind if you wish to have a simple and consistent interface is that you have a factory function, which you pass `alg_id` to, which returns a function pointer to the relevant function. Unfortunately, if the interface to each function is as I suggest, a different structure, then you still have a potential for getting the data structures and functions mixed up, but it does cut down on the number of "published functions" - in fact, those functions don't need to be visible at all outside of the module [library or even object file] that provides them.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. I understand drawbacks of this... My idea was to:
1) make it possible not to change interface of the library (keep function names the same) when adding new algorithm (so only structures will change);
2) prevent user from using the wrong structure when he or she wants to use certain algorithm, so I decided to hardcode alg_id inside of every structure.

Point 2 is easy achievable with split functions but point 1 is not. There will be some layer calling the functions of library and it won't be so easy to change its interfaces every time. Or is it a necessary extent?

Comment: If you are changing algorithms, then you probably introduce new data structures [if I understand your problem correctly], which means new header files - so introducing a new function at the same time shouldn't be a problem unless you get a name collision. Using names that are unlikely to clash with your client code's names would help here, e.g using a prefix and then documenting that "client functions should not start with `PfX_` or whatever your prefix is. The interface library undoubtedly also needs to change to support new algorithms. (more...)

Comment: Putting the `alg_id` in the `struct` doesn't help unless you make sure 1. The `alg_id` isn't in the same place for any two structs. 2. None of the data used could be confused with the value `alg_id`. Both of these will become harder and harder to achieve the more functions you add. See also edit above...