# Namespace compilation issues

Tags: c++, visual-c++, namespaces, visual-studio-2005, static-libraries

I am new to working in Visual Studio (am using version 2005). I am running into a problem with namespaces that I am not able to figure out.

I am trying to create a static library which I will link to an Application later.

So, I have a XXX.h file with the following code

```
#ifndef _XXX_X_H
#define _XXX_X_H

namespace LLL_NWK
{
   void lllInit();
}
#endif
```

I include XXX.h in XXX.c and the code looks like

```
#include "XXX.h"

using namespace LLL_NWK;

void lllInit()
{
}
```

However, when I build the Library I encounter the following errors

```
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'LLL_NWK'
error C2059: syntax error : ';'
error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
error C2059: syntax error : '}'
```

I am unable to figure out the cause of this error. Would appreciate some help and pointers.

Comment: rename `XXX.c` to `XXX.cc` or `XXX.cpp` - the compiler thinks it's plain `C` code rather than `C++` code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `using namespace LLL_NWK` is not appropriate here. You are declaring and defining a function `void lllInit()` *outside* of `namespace LLL_NWK`. You need to place the definition inside of the namespace, which can be done like this:

```
void LLL_NWK::lllInit()
{
}
```

or like this:

```
namespace LLL_NWK
{
   void lllInit()
   {
   }
}
```

Second, **make sure you compile the code as C++**.

Answer (score 0):

That code is not supported by the C compiler - makes sure to rename the filename to .cpp instead .c. In this case, namespace is not supported. See this post: [Namespaces in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389827/namespaces-in-c)

Comment: @AdityaSehgal this won't fix everything. Your code is wrong, see my answer.

Comment: Juan point is making a valid point - so you better consider what he just said. The code above is error prone in a definition file (I'm pretty sure I've seen that kind of use of namespace in the std for patching namespace conflicts).

The code is still valid though.

Comment: @AdamGalarneau Right, it would lead to a linker error if any attempt to use `LLL_NWK::lllInit()` is made.

Comment: @AdamGalarneau : thanks for the info. have made the necessary changes.