# How can one emulate the C++ namespace feature in a C code?

Tags: c++, c, namespaces

I'm developing a software which is in C++ but that communicates with a C app through a shared header file containing the communication protocol. Since C is "more basic" than C++, I always need to write the header in C code (so C++ also gets it); otherwise it wouldn't work for the second app.

The problem is that I need to use a scope-quilifier such as the C++ `namespace`s - which don't exist in C.

**What are *all* the options to emulate the `namespace` feature in C?**

The only possibility I have seen so far is the one shown in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389827/namespaces-in-c), but unfortunately the answer is not clear enough and I would certainly like to know if there are other options. I also tried to use `struct`s to do the job, without success (at least considering a `struct` with an `enum`erator).

Comment: Don't emulate it at all. Use `#ifdef __cplusplus` to determine whether you are included by C++ sources, and add namespacing and `extern "C"` than. You might even put the declaration into an inner `internal`-namespace and use `using prefix_free_name = internal::long_prefix_laden_c_name;` in the outer public namespace.

Comment: @Deduplicator Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure, though, if I understood your suggestion - I know the `__cplusplus` thing and `extern "C"` separately, but not as a solution the scope problem I posted in my question. Could you give me an implementation example?

Comment: Just have a naming convention, e.g. like GTK where every C name is starting with `Gtk` (or `_Gtk` for `struct` tags)....

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch well actually I have naming convention already inplemented in structs, defines and the name of the enums - but not the enums content. And here is where the absence of namespace are giving me problems. But even if I do use naming conventions even for the content of enums, I'ld still have the curiosity of knowing my possibilities :)

Answer (score 12):

You can hide all of your exported functions from being exported from the module with `static` at the definition level, so that no names are placed in the global space, and instead put them in a struct that is the only thing provided by the module.

E.g. foo.h:

```
struct ns_t {
    int (*a)(int, int);
    void (*b)(float, float);
};
extern struct ns_t ns;
```

foo.c:

```
#include "foo.h"

static int a(int x, int y) {
    ...
}

static void b(float x, float y) {
    ...
}

struct ns_t ns = { .a = a, .b = b };
```

bar.c:

```
#include "foo.h"
....
ns.b(4.5, 6.8);
....
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Is it possible to do all of this code inside a header file only?

Comment: You can't prevent anything in a header file from being visible to the code that includes it, in C, although I guess you could always give the function definitions themselves extremely ungainly names to prevent accidental usage? It's not normal to put definitions in the header in C though. Doesn't work like C++.

Comment: That's an interesting take on namespaces. Though there's probably a bad effect on performance, due to always jumping through those global pointers...

Comment: "Doesn't work like C++".. you can't put function defintions in the header in C++ unless it's a template. Unless of course you love bloat and compiler errors about function redefinition.

Comment: I meant within classes. I'm not much of a C++er but I think it is normal for class definitions in headers to include code too, which won't cause any duplication errors thanks to compiler cleverness, right? And of course templates themselves.

Comment: Only very small class functions would go in the header/declaration. It inlines them that's why. So it will make the executable considerably larger and compiling will take WAY longer. I used to think that way too but I asked here: https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/423106/separate-headers-from-source  and the answer was "don't do it". lol.

Answer (score 7):

Don't emulate namespaces in C at all, go the C way:

- Use prefixes instead of namespaces.
- Use suffixes instead of overloading.

  - Optionally use a macro with `_Generic` to simulate overloading on argument-types.

Your include file should define those C functions in an inner detail-namespace for C++ (does not change the functions actual identity, due to C-linkage), and then you strip prefixes and suffixes from the C functions for C++.
It looks like this:

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER_GUARD_unique_suffix
#define MY_HEADER_GUARD_unique_suffix
#ifdef __cplusplus
namespace my_module {
namespace detail {
extern "C" {
#endif
// Defines for common structs and functions here
// Also inline functions written in the common intersection of C and C++
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
}
using init = detail::my_module_init;
using close = detail::my_module_close;
}
#endif
#endif
```

You might also want to add member-functions to some of the C structs for the C++ interface, which might be inline-functions delegating to a shared function.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Although it doesn't answer my question, it does provide an interesting suggestion for my particular problem (at least from the view of the C++ app; the C app would still lack a `namespace` equivalence). My only doubt is the significance of those two last lines (`using init` and `using close`): what are they for?

Comment: @Momergil: They are for stripping any prefixes (C alternative to namespaces) and suffixes (C alternative to overloading). BTW: You can use `_Generic` to provide an interface without suffixes in C).

Answer (score 2):

First, you start out by prefixing all exported symbols (including names of preprocessor defines and enum members) with a namespace. For example, you could have a function declaration

```
void foo_bar_baz(void);
```

On the C++ side, these need to be wrapped in `extern "C" { … }` and then should be registered with the correct namespace. Assuming C++11, in case of functions this should be as simple as

```
namespace foo {
    namespace bar {
        constexpr auto baz = foo_bar_baz;
    }
}
```

On the C side, you could define shortened names like

```
#define baz foo_bar_baz
```

use compiler-specific attributes to register an alias or add a constant declaration

```
static void (*const baz)(void) = foo_bar_baz;
```

This works out just fine because calling a function actually makes use of function pointers (instead of designators).

You could put everything into a single header with some `#ifdef`s as appropriate, or you could provide small wrappers like `foo/bar.hxx` for C++ and `foo/bar-import.h` for shortened C names in addition to `foo/bar.h` which contains the actual prefixed declarations and would be included by the other headers.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a system that very much depend on namespaces (build-type inserted-ones that is), and from my looking at C, you can imperfectly emulate `C++` namespaces (on Linux anyway) by collecting the symbols your exports for static linking, prefixing them with `objcopy` and then macro-translating your header code (excluding includes) to match the prefixed symbol set.

The problem with this is that macros don't respect scope and so assuming your library exports `void foo()` (or symbol `foo` in short) -- and you'd prefix that into `mylib_foo`, then a macro that translates `foo` into `mylib_foo` would also indiscriminately translate struct members named `foo` even though those should not be translated.

I believe that doing it right would actually require hacking at the compiler (and somebody do it please! :)).